# How to create a text file name with textbox value?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#, I want to create a file with extension `.txt` and  file name as with first three characters of textbox value.I am creating the file but i dont now how to store the file in the required destination for example c:\ Documents\ION.please help me.
Thank You For reading this...

```
     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.Text = "Create_File";

         string fileName = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 3) + ".txt";            

         File.Create(fileName);
        MessageBox.Show("ok");

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try _anything_ so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? `Substring`,`.Text`, `File.Create`? winforms/wpf/asp.net?

Comment: Looks like `c#-4.0` tag is irrelevant.

Comment: Without the code that's giving you problems, it won't be possible for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank U guys ,with all Your help I solved it

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button2.Text = "SAVE";      
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\\Users\\Apple\\Desktop\\proj").Length;
        string fileName = textBox1.Text.Substring(0, 3) + -+ ++files + ".txt";
        string path2 = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\Users\\Apple\\Desktop\\proj");
        string docPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        string var = Path.Combine(docPath, path2);
        string var1 = Path.Combine(var, fileName);
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(var1))
        {
            string var6 = textBox1.Text;
            string var7 = "                 ";
            string var8 = textBox2.Text;

            string var9 = string.Concat(var6, var7, var8);
            writer.WriteLine(var9);

        }

        MessageBox.Show("File created");
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
string fileName = textBox.Text.Substring(0,3) + ".txt";
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    writer.WriteLine("Hello world!");
}
```

Note that it would be wise to confirm that the TextBox contains at least three characters before doing that.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue i had and got it solved by doing it this way :

`File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "DataExport_"+srchCat_txtbox.Text+"_"+DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyy")+".csv", csv);`

I needed to save CSV files with a unique name which includes a global name "DataExport", a category name "srchCat_txtbox.Text" value and the current date.